# Flutter Slider, How to limit the possible input?

Tags: flutter, slider

Let's imagine the following: 
I have two Sliders, each can get input from 0 to 10.
But both together should also be limited to a max Input of 10.

So if the first Slider is set to 6, I want the second Slider to just allow Inputs from 0 to 4. But still, show the full Slider with 10 Divisions. The right side of the second Slider (5 to 10) should just be not settable for the User.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Could you provide code showing where you're at so that people can help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out

```
class TwoSliders extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TwoSlidersState createState() => _TwoSlidersState();
}

class _TwoSlidersState extends State<TwoSliders> {
  double slider1 = 0;
  double slider2 = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Slider(
              onChanged: (value) {
                if((value+slider2)<=10){
                  setState(() {
                    slider1 = value;
                  });
                }
              },
              max: 10,
              divisions: 10,
              value: slider1,
              label: slider1.toString(),
            ),
            Slider(
              onChanged: (value) {
                if((value+slider1)<=10){
                  setState(() {
                    slider2 = value;
                  });
                }
              },
              value: slider2,
              max: 10,
              divisions: 10,
              label: slider2.toString(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I am impressed by the effort you put into this. But it's not exactly what I've tried to ask for. 6 and 4 was just an example. The Input from both Sliders should be 10 or less. So if the first Slider is on 2 the second could be moved up to 8. And so on. But still Thanks.

Comment: What logic exactly?

Comment: Oh so what you’re saying is the values of the 2 sliders should sum up to 10?

Comment: @Nicolas I have edited it you can check the code out

Answer (score 0):

In both of the `onChanged()` callbacks, only update the value if it is inferior or equal to 10 minus the value of the other Slider.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but with a setup like this, I can move the sliders to for example 5 and 6 (because it updated when it was 10) and then it adds up to 11 and I can't move the Sliders anymore. I've tried to fix it with an else statement, but then I can move the Slider freely. And all my tries to do it with an else if statement ended in the first problem, that I can't move the Sliders anymore.